# Linq to work with slightly complex selectlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Here is a simplified select list

```
<select name="stuff">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option>Test</option>
    <option>Test1</option>
    <option>Test2</option>
    <option>Horses</option>
</select>
```

Based on the value from the select list, I wish to find related values from my table.

LINQ

```
1. someTable.Where(r => r.someField.Contains(stuff));
2. someTable.Where(r => r.someField == stuff);

3. var a = someTable;
if(stuff != null)
a = a.Where(r => r.someField.Contains(stuff))
```

The former solution will work properly when the "All" option is selected. Since All is represented by an empty string *stuff*, `.Contains` will return true for any case. This breaks when choosing *Test*, as it will also return *Test1* and *Test2*

The second solution (==) will work fine for all cases except *All*, and will break if I ever want to use this for a multiple select list.

The third solution will handle *All* properly, but it will still return *Test1* and *Test2* if *Test* is selected.

How can I modify this code to work with `All`, multiple select, and only selecting exact values?

Comment: Why wouldn't you do `r.someField == stuff` for the third solution?  It's confusing why you are even using `.Contains` in the first place if it gives incorrect behavior.

Comment: @mellamokb Using `==` in the third solution would work only in the case of no multi select. I ended the 2nd solution with a bit about how that would break for multi select. I should have made it a little more explicit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way or the other, you would need to add a special case to cover `"All"`, because it is, well, special. For example, you can rewrite your second solution like this:

```
someTable.Where(r => string.Empty == stuff || r.someField == stuff);
```

Comment: @mellamokb Ah, you're right, I missed that `All` is the display name, while its value is `string.Empty`. Thank you very much!

Comment: Such an obvious solution! I can't even blame my oversight on it being a Monday! Darn those Tuesdays.